# .NET SQL Azure Migrations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've finally managed to get my database to Azure! transformed my connection strings and it all logs in successfully after 3 weeks of trying.

Though just testing everything now and made a small change to my local model, ran a local migration and published again however when trying to access the Azure database it says I need to run a migration as the application DB context has changed.

How do I run migration on Azure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That depends on how you publish the application, the version of Visual Studio and the development environment, eg. MVC 5 or Core.  You can use the built in migration support from Visual Studio Publish, or set your default database to the Azure connection string and run Update-database from the Package Manager console again.
[Look at the section on Database Migration here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Locally change the connection string to point to Azure Database (you will need to log into Azure Portal => SQL database => Select the database => Set Server Firewall => Add Client IP) and run **update-database**.

The correct approach would be enabling automatic database migrations.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I found it in the publish settings in the end, with a checkbox to enable migrations :)